# csurf express.js and angular, secret overwritten by token

Tags: angular, express, csrf

I'm working on project with express.js and angular. I tried to implement csurf as explained in readme file on https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

When I debug through `csurf` source code I noticed that `secret`, generated when loading angular view is overwritten by `token` in second request. So `secret` and `token` are equal. I spent two days figuring out why that happen and what am I doing wrong.

Maybe you have idea what is wrong and can help me?

this is my express.js configuration

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const csurf = require('csurf');

const app = express();

const csrfProtection = csurf({
  cookie: {
    key: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    path: '/'
  }
});

// Parser
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// API location
app.use('/api', csrfProtection, bodyParser.json(), api);

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
  const cookie = req.csrfToken();
  console.log("COOKIE", cookie);
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', cookie);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

// Set port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```

and angular service which calls backend api

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AppService } from '../../shared/services';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login(cred: any): Promise<Response> {
    const HEADERS = new Headers();
    const csrfCookie = AppService.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
    console.log(csrfCookie);

    if (csrfCookie) {
      HEADERS.append('csrf-token', csrfCookie);
    }
    console.log(HEADERS);

    return this.http.post('/api/login', JSON.stringify(cred), { headers: HEADERS })
      .map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, can you please share your solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

@arthurr -

I haven't looked thoroughly, but the first thing that stands out is where you set:

```
// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
  const cookie = req.csrfToken();
  console.log("COOKIE", cookie);
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', cookie);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Someone correct me if wrong, but the req.csrfToken() method is generating a token from a secret.  You embed this token in a form to be submitted. It is then compared against the secret (when using the cookie mode as you are above, this is stored in the client as a cookie, which you have named XSRF-TOKEN).

So at first glance, a problem you are having is that you are trying to send the csurf COOKIE (a secret that should not be sent via request) instead of correctly sending the csurf TOKEN in the header.

Does this sound inaccurate?